# Unit test for reading/writing files

Tags: unit-tests

I finished my studies recently and I am a junior developer.
The problem is that I'm the only computer scientist in my company and I am afraid of taking bad habits because nobody is here to tell me how to "work properly".
My question is about Unit tests. I understand unit test when it comes to "basic mathematics" => unit tests are here for testing if our multiplication function works fine with limite cases and things like this.

But what about reading/writing files? I'm actually reading and writing e57 files (point cloud file), and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't works (depend from where the e57 files come). So I would like to do unit tests to test my functions. But what would be a unit test for reading/writing an header for example?

I hope this is understandable and the right place to post this question.

Thanks !

Comment: When you say "sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't works", are you talking about the serialization process or something else, on the business rules of your software?

Comment: Well! That wasn't clear sorry! 
When I finish processing the file, when I want to import it into a vizualisation software.  Sometimes I can import it, sometimes I can't because the file is malformated for it.
That's why I want to be sure that the problem don't come from my program, but by the software I'm using afterwards (it would not be the first time that the soft is broken)